# With Rails form builder, is there a way to have a checked check box equal a false value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

This is for using the `f.check_box` method in a Rails `form_for` block.

The checkbox represents a bool attribute on the model.  But, I want checked to equal false and unchecked to equal true.  Checked (false) is also the default value.

So if a user leaves it checked and submits the form, the model attribute will be false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-check_box). You should be fine with

```
f.check_box :something, {}, 0, 1
```

The `0` and `1` are the checked and unchecked values, respectively.

**Update:** I thought the checkbox would be checked/unchecked correctly when given its checked/unchecked values, but if that isn't the case, you can do this:

```
f.check_box :something, { :checked => !@model.something }, 0, 1
```

I.e. explicitly tell the checkbox to be checked when the attribute is false, and unchecked when it's true.

However, it's getting a bit confusing to always flip the values. Perhaps the "judo" way of handling it would be to rename the attribute, so Rails' default behavior of false = unchecked can be used.

**2nd update:** The semantics of a checkbox are really very clear: Checked means true (hence Rails' default behavior). So if you're using the checkbox "backwards" I imagine there's a issue with your domain model. If a user checks the box, that user is answering something in the affirmative (e.g. "Yes, I want your newsletter" or "Yes, I want to stay logged in").
If your model then has to flip that around, your model's attribute is backwards compared to user intention and maybe a double negative (e.g. "yes, I want your newsletter" becoming `no_newsletter = false`). I imagine it must be simpler to model it in straightforward terms.

Comment: Is there a way to have it checked upon page load?